# Having problems with declaring an object of one class(UserDAL) within the other class(User_Service)

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to declare an object of class UserDAL within the class User_Service, but I am unable to do so in the way shown below. I get "HTTP ERROR 500"
However, I can declare the object within a function which is not a good practice

```
<?php

require_once "UserDAL.php";

    class User_Service 
    { 


        $UserDALobject = new UserDAL();

        public function showAllUsers()
        { 
            $UserdataArray = $UserDALobject->getAllUsers();

            foreach($UserdataArray as $user)   
                {
                    echo "<br>ID : ".$user->id."    ||  "; 
                    echo "Name : ".$user->name."    ||  "; 
                    echo "E Mail : ".$user->email." "; 
                }
        }
    }
         $users = new User_Service(); 
         $users->showAllUsers(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: *"within the other class"* - Which other class is that?

Comment: User_Service is the class

Comment: you can initialise a class from within an object if you do so in the constructor

Comment: I'll quote you completely. Your title states: *"Having problems with declaring an using object of one class within the other class"* - There is only 1 class here. What other class are you talking about?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner He is trying to initialise `UserDAL` class from within `User_Service`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ok I will make it specific

Comment: @peterxz I know that. Their title is confusing and misleading.

Comment: @M.B have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of initialising the new object as a class variable, initialise the variable `$UserDALobject` to `null` and in the constructor initialise `UserDAL`

```
class User_Service {
    $UserDALobject = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $UserDALobject = new UserDAL;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `public $UserDALobject = NULL;  public function __construct() { this->UserDALobject = new UserDAL(); }` like this you mean ?

Comment: `$this->...` and `UserDal;`, but otherwise yes, that should work. i usually do it this way, if it doesnt work then something else within `UserDAL` is causing the HTTP error